# typescript does not recognize exported enum

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

I'm using `TypeScript 2.5.3` and `Angular 5`.
There is an `enum` declared in a separate file like this:

```
export enum eUserType {
  Driver = 1,
  Passenger = 2,
  User = 3
}
```

And import/use it in other `ts` file like so:

```
import { eUserType } from '../CorrectFilePath/eUserType';
export class ViewsModule { 
  newVariable=eUserType.Driver;
}
```

While intellisense works OK, an error will raise on run-time: `Cannot read property 'Driver' of undefined`.
Am i misusing `enum` or what?

Update:
I don't know if it is related or not. but, **The target module is lazy loaded** and a `PreloadingStrategy` class (declared in a file other than module's file) used there, and my `enum` applied to `PreloadingStrategy` class.

Comment: I don't get any run time error with your code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-enum

Comment: Can you share the code where `ViewsModule` is used?

Comment: **The target module is lazy loaded** and a `PreloadingStrategy` class (declared in a file other than module's file) used there, and my `enum` applied to `PreloadingStrategy` class.

Comment: Does it work with `export const enum eUserType {...}`?

Comment: @Alex Szabó Yeeesssss. but why???

Comment: @Rzassar - I'm not sure what's wrong with your setup, it looks perfectly fine from what I can see - and I'm not familiar enough with lazy loading to be able to tell, *but* you are using `1, 2, 3` as enum values (which could be omitted), and `export const enum` will not create an object and try to reference that, but actually put the values where you would use them. I think for your use case, this would be a perfect fit -> https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums

Comment: @AlexSzabó ,why dont you write it as answer so i can mark it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably not going to help you in what's the current issue (your setup seems fine), and I'm not familiar enough with lazy loading to be able to tell, but you are using `1, 2, 3` as enum values (which could be omitted), and `export const enum` will not create an object and try to reference that, but actually put the values where you would use them. I think for your use case, this would be a perfect fit: http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
euserType = eUserType;
newVariable=euserType.Driver;
```